# Authentication Using Next Auth + Rails API Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, next.js

so I have a Nextjs frontend that is using Next Auth for authentication. This will be using a variety of Oauth providers but for this example and to prove the concept I am just using the `github` provider.

First, the next app is barebones and uses the default config for Nextjs and Next auth.

It has one special route

`/pages/api/protected/[...requests].js`

The purpose of this route is to act as a middleman to wrap up requests with the JWT provided by Next Auth and sent to the server API. It passes through any server errors returned to the client.

EG:

`http://localhost:3000/api/protected/users` -> `http://localhost:4000/users`
`http://localhost:3000/api/protected/widgets` -> `http://localhost:4000/widgets`
`http://localhost:3000/api/protected/users/1/widgets` -> `http://localhost:4000/users/1/widgets`

source:

```js
// Catch all that basically authorizes any request to the backend
// api and adds the JWT token to the request headers. No Special 
// magic is done here besides adding the token to the request.

import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import QueryString from 'qs'
import getAccessToken from '@util/getAccessToken'
import fetchWithStatus from '@apiWrapper/fetchWithStatus'

const getAccessToken = ({req}) => {
  const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
  const info = await getToken({ req, secret })
  if (info === null) {
    return null
  } else {
    return (info.accessToken)
  }
}

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let accessToken = await getAccessToken({ req })
    const { request, ...qs } = req.query
    const path = request.join('/')
    let opts = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer: ${accessToken}`
      },
      method: req.method
    }
    if (req.method === 'POST' || req.method === 'PUT') {
      opts.body = JSON.stringify(req.body)
      opts.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    }
    const { data, status } = await fetchWithStatus(`${process.env.API_SERVER}/${path}?${QueryString.stringify(qs)}`, opts)
    res.status(status).json({ status: status, data: data })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message)
  }
}
```

Then the request is authenticated on the Rails API by providing a `current_user` based on the decoded JWT.

```rb
class ApplicationController < Rails::ApiController

  before_action :authenticate!

  private

  def authenticate!
    begin
      @user = JwtService::Decode(request.headers['Authorization'])
    rescue JwtService::AuthorizationError # Catches Decode errors, etc...
      head 401
    end
  end

  def current_user
    @user
  end
end
```

As you can see, I believe making what in a normal application would be 1 api request has now turned into 3 + any external calls that need to be made to decode the JWT.

The upside to this approach in my (uneducated) opinion, is I can offload almost all of the user authentication logic to Next Auth and not worry about it too much.

Is there a better or different way I should be approaching this?